# Prevent Console Window Being Resized / Scrolled In C (Window.h)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, resize

I'm using window.h in my C program and want to be able to prevent the user from resizing the console window.

Is it possible to remove the scroll bars and "drag to resize" functions (shown in image) of the console window in using C?

[image]

Comment: It's not quite a best practice to mess with user's settings of a console window. Users can decide themselves if they like scroll bars or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the scroll bars by setting the console text buffer size to the same size as the viewport (tested with Windows 7).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &info)) {
        COORD coord;
        coord.X = info.srWindow.Right - info.srWindow.Left + 1;
        coord.Y = info.srWindow.Bottom - info.srWindow.Top + 1;
        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsoleOutput, coord);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Although this will not prevent from changing the buffer size back by a user.